# Make text fixt to an area

Tags: html, css

MY CODE IS:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <div class="statistic-box statistic-filled-1">
    <h1><span class=count-number>5251111111</span>TL</h1>
    <span class=slight><i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-270 text-warning"> </i> 28%</span>
    <div class=small>Stok</div>
    <div>
      <a href=stok> <i class="ti-server statistic_icon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: this is not wanted]

i want to edit the text so that it would fit  and not disturb the server image, is there anyway to make this possible?

Comment: Change the font size? Change the width of the span? There are many options what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image as the divs background image & then set padding on the div.

Comment: how do i do this i am very beginner at hml can you link me ?

Comment: I think I have a solution add a float:right; to the css of the server image. This way the text will wrap around the image.  You can use this:   word-wrap: break-word;  on the box that has the text so that it will wrap to the next line.

Comment: Another solution might be to set the width of "statistic-box statistic-filled-1" to say 75% (or any number that fits), Then you can set the font-size to font-size:5vh & it will resize based on the width of the div

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your CSS, it looks like you are probably using a `background-image` property on one of your div elements. The text appearing over top of it is how it's intended to work.

If you don't want this image to be part of the background, then I'd suggest removing that property and instead inserting a good old fashioned `<img>` element in the HTML instead.